# Get unix timestamp in milliseconds with perl

Tags: perl, nginx, unix-timestamp

I understand we can use the `time()` function to get the `seconds` elapsed since the epoch. How do I get the `milliseconds` though?

I'm doing an interop with a JavaScript based system where we deal with `milliseconds`.

Thanks! Btw, I'm gonna be evaluating this script in the context of nginx.

Answer (score 10):

You could make your own `time` which return a floating point number like this:

```
use Time::HiRes;
sub time_fp { sprintf"%d.%06d",Time::HiRes::gettimeofday }
```

Or just override the core `time` like this:

```
use Time::HiRes qw(time);
print time(), "\n";             # 1530190722.02601 for example
```

A problem though with the latter is that it's not room for 6 decimals (if you want microseconds instead of milliseconds) after that 10 digit number in a standard floating point number (might depend on Perl version and compile settings). Run `perl -le 'print 1530190907.849523'` to see what I mean. The last decimal 3 is lost.

Comment: Points for not being rude.

Answer (score 4):

It pays off to [read the documentation](http://p3rl.org/time).

[Time::HiRes](http://p3rl.org/Time::HiRes)